# When i quickly move my mouse pointer on menu bar slide down and slide up, it is fluctuating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
          (function($){

            //cache nav
            var nav = $("#topNav");

            //add indicator and hovers to submenu parents
            nav.find("li").each(function() {
                if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
                    $("<span>").text("^").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));

                    //show subnav on hover
                    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                        $(this).find("ul").stop(true,true).slideDown();
                    });

                    //hide submenus on exit
                    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                        $(this).find("ul").stop(true,true).slideUp();
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

*Following is my code which i am using for slideUp and SlideDown of submenus.but when i continues slide on menu to slide down and slide up,then menus are fluctuating.*

Comment: Can you [set up a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have created my menubar on jsFiddel but it is not giving same output to me as i getting it on my pc.

Comment: I got my answer .I have made changes in sequence of stop() and slideUP and slideDown and added slidUp("slow") and slideDown("slow"). now my  menu bar is not fluctuaing  .Now sequence is like  -$(this).find("ul").slideDown("slow").stop(true,true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have observed this behaviour before and I was only able to find an adequate solution by using the jQuery UI library to do effects on hide/show.

If you include the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library you can use the following code which might not be optimal but it does not flicker or fluctuate.

```
//cache nav
var nav = $("#topNav");

//add indicator and hovers to submenu parents

nav.find("li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
        $("<span>").text("^").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));
        var $subMenu = $(this).find("ul");
        //show subnav on hover
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                // --> this causes flicker $subMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown();
                $subMenu.stop(true,true).show("slide", {direction: "up"});
            },
            function() {
                // --> this causes flicker $subMenu.stop(true,true).slideUp();
                $subMenu.stop(true,true).hide("slide", {direction: "up"});
            }
        );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/k7akm/2/